# Return None in function: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, lda, nonetype

I am trying to print my topics and texts from each topic in `LDA`. But a None after printing the topics is disrupting my script. I can print my topics but not the texts.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

n_top_words = 5
n_components = 5

def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        message = "Topic #%d: " % topic_idx
        message += " ".join([feature_names[i] for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])

        return message

text = pandas.read_csv('text.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
text_list = text.values.tolist()

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_list)

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=n_components, learning_method='batch', max_iter=25, random_state=0)

doc_distr = lda.fit_transform(tf)

tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print (print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words))

doc_distr = lda.fit_transform(tf)
topics = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
for i in range(len(topics)):
    print ("Topic {}:".format(i))
    docs = np.argsort(doc_distr[:, i])[::-1]
    for j in docs[:10]:
       print (" ".join(text_list[j].split(",")[:2]))
```

My output:

```
Topic 0: no order mail received back 

Topic 1: cancel order wishes possible wish 

Topic 2: keep current informed delivery order 

Topic 3: faulty wooden box present side 

Topic 4: delivered received be produced urgent 

Topic 5: good waiting day response share
```

Followed by this error:

```
  File "lda.py", line 41, in <module>

    for i in range(len(topics)):

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: the value of topic is None for that iteration.

Comment: Seems your `print_top_words` have problem with returning `message`. Check the `for` loop in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) four issues with your `print_top_words()` function.

The first one - which causes your current problem - is that if `model.components_` is empty, the for loop's body will not execute, and your function will then (implicitely) return `None`.

The second one is a bit more subtle: if `model.components_` is NOT empty, the function will return only the first message, then return it and exit - which the very definition of the `return` statement: return a value (or `None` if no value is specified) and exit the function.

The third issue is that (when `model.components_` is not empty), the function returns a string, where the calling code obviously expects a list. This is a subtle bug because strings have a length so the for loop on `range(len(topics))` **seems** to work, but `len(topics)` is very certainly not the value you expect.

And finally, the function is very badly named since it doesn't "print" anything - this mights seem trivial compared to the first three issues, and it will not prevent the code from working indeed (assuming the first three issues are fixed), but reasoning about code is difficult enough by itself so proper naming **is** important as it greatly reduces the cognitive load and make maintenance / debugging easier.

To make a long story short: think about what you really want this function to do and fix it appropriately. I won't post a "corrected" version here since I do not know for sure what you're trying to do, but the above notes should help.

NB : also, you're calling `doc_distr = lda.fit_transform(tf)` and `print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)` twice with the exact same arguments, which is either totally useless and a pure waste of processer cycles (in the best case) or the smell of yet another bug if you get different results from the second call.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the full code, but the most likely reason is that variable `topics` is None. The only way that can happen is if `model.components_` in your `print_top_words` function is an empty collection, so the loop never runs, and the function (implicitly) returns None. Check the value of the collection. Better yet, choose a value to be returned in that case.

Another, unrelated, point: you initialize your `message` variable at every iteration, and you return it at every iteration. Check what you mean to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hard to answer without knowledge of the inner workings of a `LatentDirichletAllocation`. However, it's components_ has something to do with it, because repeated iteration of it yields different results.

You can most likely avoid this error by changing:

```
print (print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words))

doc_distr = lda.fit_transform(tf)
topics = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
```

to:

```
temp = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
print (temp)

doc_distr = lda.fit_transform(tf)
topics = print_top_words(temp)
```

The second time you call the function, model.components_ returns nothing, so the loop is skipped and the function returns none.

However, I'm not sure whether that is the actual intention of the code. It looks like you might want print_top_words to be a generator ? You're returning inside of the for loop, which makes it never ever reach a second iteration. That's probably not what the loop is meant for.